# CSS same-line aligning

Tags: css, user-interface, alignment, positioning

Is there an elegant way to align 3 elements left, center, and right on the same line?

Right now I'm using 3 `<div>`'s all with width:33%;float:left; and it's not working too well.

Comment: can you attach a full code sample?

Answer (score 7):

that works for me:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      div.fl {
        float: left;
        width: 33%;
      }
      div.fr {
        float: right;
        width: 33%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="fl">
      A
    </div>
    <div class="fl">
      B
    </div>
    <div class="fr">
      C
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

do you mean the same?

Answer (score 2):

You may get strange results if there is any margin in the element you are adding it to. This is where `width: 33%` may not work because you will need to factor in the amount of margin that element has.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
div { float: left; width: 33%; margin: 4px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="border: 1px solid #ff0000;">1</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid #00ff00;">2</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid #0000ff;">3</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This will cause it not work as expected because of the margin added to each div. Similarly, if you add too much of a border to each div you will get a similar result `border: 5px solid !important;`

As soon as you take away the margin from the above code, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 100px;">
    left
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 100px;">
    right
</div>
<div style="width: 100px; margin: 0 auto;">
    center
</div>
```

You need to take into account that the left and right divs do not push the container box (a div around the code above) height down, even if they have more content than the center div, the only one not floated. A clearfix will take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

I created a page with all three methods for comparison at http://www.salestime.com/Ref/LeftCenterRight.html.

Answer (score 0):

Float the first two left and float the third one right, while ensuring the widths will fit the line you are placing them on.

Use pixel widths if your design allows for it.

Answer (score 0):

Float LeftBlock 'left', CenterBlock 'none' and RightBlock 'right'. But **make sure the Center element appears last on your HTML page**, otherwise it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another varition of the theme:-

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    div div {border:1px solid black}
    div.Center {width:34%; float:left; text-align:center}
    div.Left {float:left; width:33%; text-align:left}
    div.Right {float:right; width:33%; text-align:right}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Left"><div>Left</div></div><div class="Center"><div>Center</div></div><div class="Right"><div>Right</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the border is possible by using an inner div for each of the 'panel' divs. Also gives the center the remain 1% of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I don't know if it's the most elegant, but it does do the work: it reacts well to the "cell" contents and resizing.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .a {
                border: 1px dotted grey;
                padding: 2px;
                margin: 2px;
            }
            .l {
                border: 1px solid red;
                background-color: #fee;
                float:left;
            }
            .c {
                border: 1px solid green;
                background-color: #efe;
                text-align:center;
            }
            .r {
                border: 1px solid blue;
                background-color: #eef;
                float:right;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="l">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <div class="r">
                toto v.2 adfsdfasdfa sdfa dfas asdf 
            </div>
            <div class="c">
                item 1 | tiem 2 | asdf 3 | asdfad asd | aasdfadfadfads
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```